# problemas al usar canvas en kivy

Tags: canvas, kivy

estoy arrancando con  kivy y me surgió un problema, cuando uso canvas para darle color a una boxlayout desde el archivo .kv se me cierra la ventana, si saco el canvas el error no esta, no entiendo cual seria el problema

```
import kivy
kivy.require('2.1.0')

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Cont_1(BoxLayout):
    None

class MainApp(App):
    title='Control de stock'
    def build(self):
        return Cont_1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

en esta parte es donde esta el problema, si elimino la parte de canvas la ventana abre bien, sino abre y se cierra sola

```
#:kivy 2.1.0

<Cont_1>:
    canvas:
        color:
            rgb: 1,1,1
        rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    Button:
        text: 'Agregar producto'

    Button:
        text: 'Eliminar producto'

    Button:
        text: 'Modificar Stock'

    Button:
        text: 'Salir'
```

Comment: Basicamente pyhton reconoce entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por lo tanto  color y rectangle deben ir en mayúscula la primer letra: Color Rectangle, no vi otro error

Comment: gracias capo, el editor no me marcaba ningún error x eso no sabia cual era el problema

Comment: **Color** y **Rectangle** deben tener su primera letra en mayúscula.